# Loading Data into an empty Impala Table with account data partitioned by area code

Tags: syntax, partitioning, impala

I'm trying to copy data from a table called accounts into an empty table called accounts_by_area_code. I have the following fields in accounts_by_area_code: acct_num INT, first_name STRING, last_name STRING, phone_number STRING. The table is partitioned by areacode (the first 3 digits of phone_number.

I need to use a SELECT statement to extract the area code into an INSERT INTO TABLE command to copy the speciﬁed columns to the new table, dynamically partitioning by area code.

This is my last attempt:

```
impala-shell -q "INSERT INTO TABLE accounts_by_areacode (acct_num, first_name, last_name, phone_number, areacode) PARTITION (areacode) SELECT STRLEFT (phone_number,3) AS areacode FROM accounts;"
```

This generates ERROR: AnalysisException: Column permutation and PARTITION clause mention more columns (5) than the SELECT / VALUES clause and PARTITION clause return (1). I'm not convinced I have even the basic syntax correct so any help would be great as I'm new to Impala.

Answer (score 0):

Impala creates partitions dynamically based on data. So not sure why you want to create an empty table with partitions because it will be auto created while inserting new data.
Still, I think you can create empty table with partitions like this-
`impala-shell -q "INSERT INTO TABLE accounts_by_areacode (acct_num) PARTITION (areacode)
 SELECT  CAST(NULL as STRING), STRLEFT (phone_number,3) AS areacode FROM accounts;"`